# How to inherit correctly field in div

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

how to inherit correctly field 
I inherited a field but did not appear as required, because it is inside a div

```xml
<group name="email_template_and_project" position="before">
    <group name="sale_condition" string="Sale Conditions">
        <label for="warranty" groups="stock.group_production_lot"/>
        <div groups="stock.group_production_lot">
            <field name="warranty" class="oe_inline"/> months
        </div>
        <label for="sale_delay"/>
        <div>
            <field name="sale_delay" attrs="{'readonly':[('sale_ok','=',False)]}" class="oe_inline" style="vertical-align:baseline"/> days
        </div>
    </group>
</group>
```

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_template_es_">
    <field name="name">product.template.es.form</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_delay']" position="after">
            <div>
                <field name = 'time_pose' /> hours
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

[image: field add]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_product_template_es_">
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='sale_delay']/parent::div" position="after">
            <label for="time_pose"/>
            <div>
                <field name="time_pose" class="oe_inline"/> hours
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```